# Error on bar 0: The study references too many candles in history (5001)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to create a simple ruler that displays data for a selected date range. I have no problems with the code when using chart data, as seen in the example below. However, when I try using data from another symbol via request.security, the code stops working after 5000 bars. Is there a way to make it work beyond 5000 bars?

```
//@version=5
indicator("ruler", overlay=true)

//input dates
fromDate = input.time(timestamp("2023-05-10T00:00:00"), "Calculate from date:")
toDate = input.time(timestamp("2023-06-10T00:00:00"), "Calculate to date:")

//current timeframe from 1m to 2h
int currentTF = timeframe.period == '1'? 1 : timeframe.period == '5' ? 5: timeframe.period == '15' ? 15 : timeframe.period == '30' ? 30 : timeframe.period == '60' ? 60 : timeframe.period == '120' ? 120 : na

//bar indexes
fromDateIndex=(last_bar_time-fromDate)/60000/currentTF
toDateIndex=(last_bar_time-toDate)/60000/currentTF

//price change calc
pricediff=math.round(100*(close[toDateIndex+1]-open[fromDateIndex])/open[fromDateIndex],1)

//volumes calc
float sumvol=0

for i=(toDateIndex+1) to fromDateIndex
    sumvol += volume[i]

//tables
var testTable = table.new(position = position.bottom_right, columns = 8, rows = 2, border_width = 1)

table.cell(table_id = testTable, column = 0, row = 0, text_color = #b2b5be, text = "Change")
table.cell(table_id = testTable, column = 0, row = 1, text_halign= text.align_right, text_color = #b2b5be ,text = str.tostring(pricediff)+'%')

table.cell(table_id = testTable, column = 1, row = 0, text_color = #b2b5be, text = "Volume")
table.cell(table_id = testTable, column = 1, row = 1, text_halign= text.align_right, text_color = #b2b5be ,text = str.tostring(sumvol)+'M')

//spotdata
string userSymbol = syminfo.prefix + ":" + syminfo.ticker

string imData = str.replace(userSymbol, ".P","")

string selTimeframe = syminfo.type == "futures" and timeframe.isintraday ? "1D" : timeframe.period
[imvolume,imhigh, imlow, imclose] = request.security(imData, selTimeframe, [volume,high,low,close], ignore_invalid_symbol = true)
```